# Solver to run Logistic Regression using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, statistics, logistic-regression

I have created a function that gives me  the log of the verisimilitude function in VBA ; this function requires to enter 3 parameters: Independent range(x), Dependent range(y) and betas' values (B)

```
option base 1
Public Function LogVerosimilitud(RangoX As Range, RangoY As Range, B As Range) As Variant
Application.Volatile
 Dim n%, m%, i%, j%, k%, X() As Variant, p() As Variant, q() As Variant, g As Double, V() As Variant
  Dim acumula As Double, LogVero As Double
   If B.Rows.Count > B.Columns.Count Then
    Application.Transpose (B)
     End If
  g = 0
  n = RangoX.Rows.Count
  m = B.Columns.Count
  k = 0
 ReDim X(n, m)
 ReDim p(n)
 ReDim q(n)
 ReDim V(n)
   For i = 1 To n
    For j = 1 To m
     If j = 1 Then
      X(i, j) = 1
    Else
     k = k + 1
     X(i, j) = RangoX(i, k)
    End If
   Next j
   k = 0
 Next i
 For i = 1 To n
  For j = 1 To m
  g = g + X(i, j) * B(1, j)
   Next j
   p(i) = Exp(g) / (1 + Exp(g))
   q(i) = 1 - p(i)
   g = 0
 Next i
  For i = 1 To n
   V(i) = RangoY(i) * Application.Ln(p(i)) + (1 - RangoY(i)) * Application.Ln(q(i))
    Next i
LogVerosimilitud = Application.Sum(V)

End Function
```

Sincé I'm not able to use Solver directly in a UDF I want to run my function in an specific cell and then in another cell run an auxiliary function that call a sub in which I'm triying to run Excel's solver

```
Sub Solver(Target, Rango)
    SolverOk SetCell:=Target.Address, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Rango.Address, _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

This is my auxiliary function:

```
Public Function LOGIT(LogVero As Range, B As Range) As Boolean
 Debug.Print LogVero.Address
 Debug.Print B.Address
 Call Solver(LogVero.Address, B.Address)
End Function
```

But when running LOGIT function I got a #Value error in the cell I'm running LOGIT function

What am I doing wrong?

This how my data look like:

[image]

Comment: One thing to check is mismatched data types in the args passed when calling `Solver` from `LOGIT`. `Call Solver(LogVero.Address, B.Address)` passes two `String`s to `LOGIT`. But it looks like those should be `Range`s because inside the sub `Solver` you access the `.Address` property. (`String` doesn't have an `.Address` property. The compiler can warn about these types of mismatches if you use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: I think that your approach wont work for a simple reason: in the context of a UDF, you cannot change the state or value of another cell. Since you invoke the solver, you are trying to do that. It won't work. Ultimately, you need to google for hacks to break this rule.